# impl Display trait for Vec

Tags: rust, traits, display, fmt

How to implement the display trait int the below code to print just like this: `1 3 5 7 9`

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1,3,5,7,9];
    println!("{}",vec);
}
```

I tried several ways to simplify the input output for competitive programming for not to kill taking input output.